# Error using Google Play services

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am trying to use the google play service locations API. 
I have installed the Google Repositories from the sdk manager.

I am using Eclipse and for importing the locations jar I went to:
path_to_sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/9.0.0

I have unziped the aar file and added the classes.jar file to the libs folder in my project. And also included as a library for the project.

After adding the code:

```
public class ListenerService extends Service {
     public void onCreate() {
         mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    }
}
```

I get this error in eclipse:

```
The type com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zzf cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: show more code, so we can get a better idea. it looks like you are using this when it is probobly in an anonymous class when it should be using context

Comment: I modified the code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`play-services-location` depends on other AARs: `play-services-base`, `play-services-basement`, `play-services-maps`, `play-services-tasks` and `firebase-common` (from looking at the POM file for 9.0).

You'll need to include those in your app to be sure of having all classes resolved.